# What is wrong here in my C# Program?

Tags: c#

I want to search a particular word in a defined `string` for which I am using the `foreach` key word, but it's not working.

I am just a beginner at this. Please help me what is wrong in this and I don't want to use arrays.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "Hello You are welcome";

    foreach (string item in str)     // can we use string here?
    {
        if (str.Contains(are);      // I am checking if the word "are" is present in the above string 
            Console.WriteLine("True");
            )
    }
```

Comment: The error message (which you did not even include) clearly tells you that you cannot do this. You need to [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) the string to get an array

Comment: Also why are you even trying to use `foreach`? `str.Contains("are")` already checks if a word is in the string

Comment: The compiler will tell you the answer to some of your **yes/no** questions, like "Can we use String here?", the compiler says "Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'", so clearly **no**.

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "Hello You are welcome";

if (str.Contains("are"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
```

or you mean:

```
string str = "Hello You are welcome";

foreach (var word in str.Split()) // split the string (by space)
{
    if (word == "are")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @TestProgrammer Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: The latter is likely what you want - the former will return true if `bare` is a word in the string, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string str = "Hello You are welcome";
    foreach (var item in str.Split(' ')) // split the string (by space)
    {
       if (item == "are")
       {
           Console.WriteLine("True");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That still won't compile